# GO Websocket send all clients a message

Tags: go, websocket

Everything works fine with this code (shortened it for better reading).

When `Client1` sends a request to the Server, the Server responses to him instantly. But, the other clients can not see the response message.

So I want to make it go further: When a client sends a request to the server, the server will response to all clients so that all clients can see the message.

How can I do that? Any examples or nice tutorials for beginners?

Thanks in advance!

Server:

```
import (
        "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
       )

func main() {
    http.Handle("/server", websocket.Handler(echoHandler)) 
}

func echoHandler(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil) 
    if err != nil { 
      return
    }
    for {
      messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage() 
      if err != nil {
        return
      }

      print_binary(p) // simple print of the message

      err = conn.WriteMessage(messageType, p);
      if err != nil {
        return
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use connection pool to broadcast messages to all connections.
You can use that as tutorial/sample http://gary.burd.info/go-websocket-chat

Simplifying:
Connection pool is a collection of registered connections. See `hub.connections`:

```
type connection struct {
    // The websocket connection.
    ws *websocket.Conn

    // Buffered channel of outbound messages.
    send chan []byte

    // The hub.
    h *hub
}

type hub struct {
    // Registered connections. That's a connection pool
    connections map[*connection]bool

    ...
}
```

To broadcast message for all clients, we iterate over connection pool like this:

```
    case m := <-h.broadcast:
        for c := range h.connections {
            select {
            case c.send <- m:
            default:
                delete(h.connections, c)
                close(c.send)
            }
        }
    }
```

`h.broadcast` in that example is a channel with messages we need to broadcast.
We use `default` section of the `select` statement to delete connections with full or blocked send channels. See [What is the benefit of sending to a channel by using select in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693931/what-is-the-benefit-of-sending-to-a-channel-by-using-select-in-go)

Comment: Can we extract some sample code to put here? Just in case the link dies. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/306913

Comment: Thanks for that HectorJ --- the link is now dead!