# Websocket send all clients a message in Echo Framework

Tags: go, websocket, go-echo

I believe that this question is almost the same with [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532652/go-websocket-send-all-clients-a-message)

But I use websocket in Echo framework instead of Gorilla. So I think the approach will be different.

Echo does provide the [example.](http://labstack.com/echo/recipes/websocket) But it only shows how to connect with single client. When there are more than one client, the other clients don't receive message from server.

How do I make the server broadcasts message to all connected clients?

The accepted answer from referred link says that I have to use connection pool to broadcast messages to all connections. How can I do this in Echo framework?

Comment: You better off using some form of publish subscribe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You indeed need to follow the same principle of connection pool.

Here is the Echo example, with a very basic implementation of a pool:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "sync"

    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    mw "github.com/labstack/echo/middleware"
    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
)

var connectionPool = struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    connections map[*websocket.Conn]struct{}
}{
    connections: make(map[*websocket.Conn]struct{}),
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.Use(mw.Logger())
    e.Use(mw.Recover())

    e.Static("/", "public")
    e.WebSocket("/ws", func(c *echo.Context) (err error) {
        ws := c.Socket()

        connectionPool.Lock()
        connectionPool.connections[ws] = struct{}{}

        defer func(connection *websocket.Conn){
            connectionPool.Lock()
            delete(connectionPool.connections, connection)
            connectionPool.Unlock()
        }(ws)

        connectionPool.Unlock()

        msg := ""

        for {
            if err = websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &msg); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            err = sendMessageToAllPool(msg)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            fmt.Println(msg)
        }
        return err
    })

    e.Run(":1323")
}

func sendMessageToAllPool(message string) error {
    connectionPool.RLock()
    defer connectionPool.RUnlock()
    for connection := range connectionPool.connections {
        if err := websocket.Message.Send(connection, message); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hector. I got this working like a charm.